# Ubuntu 20.04 with touchpad and multi-screen not detected on recent (2023) Dell laptop

Tags: drivers, dell, touchpad, screen

Having a new Dell laptop (Precision 7780) I have to install Ubuntu 20.04, and it gives touchpad and multi-screen not detected problem.
Although on my old Dell (precision 7730) laptop the problems were not present.
I tried commands to detect touchpad (like xinput), to detect screens, multi-screen because laptop screen is ok (like xrandr) but nothing detected.
My nvidia driver is driver-meta-525 (seen on additional-drivers).

Some notes:

-When booting on BIOS I can use touchpad, so I think it is not hardware issue.

-About screen monitors detection, when I plug eg via HDMI to laptop's port still no screen detected.

I checked on Dell website for drivers they propose (close to my conditions) "Ubuntu 22.04" as option but also "Not known" and on this last option I can see only a BIOS firmware upgrade file download option.

Some questions I'm asking :

- What if I switch to XOrg nouveau on additional-drivers ?
- What if I upgrade the Dell BIOS Firmware ?
- May I need to change on Kernel ?

So what can I do to be able to use touchpad and multi-screen detection on Ubuntu version 20.04 on the Dell presision 7780 ?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't expect older releases to work on new hardware. If you can't update the OS, install a recent kernel

Comment: Hi,
Thank you, somehow when we do a kernel update wouldn't be like we update also the distro (20.04 to 22.04) ? Because I have some packages I have to run in Ubuntu 20.04 
Wouldn't the kernel update break my current setup ?

My current kernel version on my Ubuntu 20.04 is :
$ uname -r
5.15.0-82-generic

Comment: No, your existing packages should continue working

Comment: Ok , it will be good to check it, by the way my current version is :
$ uname -r
5.15.0-82-generic

And the available kernels:
$ apt list linux-*image-* gives: 

linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-78-generic/focal-security,focal-updates 5.15.0-78.85~20.04.1 amd64
linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-82-lowlatency/focal-security,focal-updates 5.15.0-82.91~20.04.1 amd64
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-100-generic/focal-security,focal-updates 5.4.0-100.113 amd64
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-1001-iot/focal-security,focal-updates 5.4.0-1001.3 amd64
..
So it looks like I'm already updated is'nt it  ?

Comment: So maybe I have to upgrdae my Ubuntu 20.04 kernel with an image kernel of Ubuntu 22.04 ? Then it will fix the dirvers issues and still being in distro Ubuntu 20.04, can this be a solution ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Try 6.2 or 6.5 kernel for example

Comment: Thanks, so ok maybe to upgrade to new version of kernel I can follolw those steps right ?
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-6.2.0-xx-generic